# Is my Rss Reader app not working because there are too many parsers (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, wordpress, parsing, android-studio, xml-parsing

I'm a high school student working for a magazine in South Korea known as Teen 10 Magazine. As an aspiring computer science major, I decided to make an RSS reader app for my magazine in order to showcase my skills for college applications (and also to create an app, which has always been my interest). Basically, I want to format my app to be similar to your typical news app (ex. CNN, BBC, etc).

[Category Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tq81.png)

In a DrawerLayout (as seen in the Category Screen), I decided to make a tab for each different category (such as News, Features, Entertainment, etc), including the Home category, which is where the categories the articles are under don't matter. When users click on each different tab, it gives them a list of articles that are categorized under that category. In order to get this data, I'm parsing the data to get the title (which is displayed in the list) and the link (which is set to an Intent so that users can access the article in the Web when it is clicked)

However, while some of the categories do work (Home, Lifestyle, Fashion), the rest of the categories are stuck in the loading screen for almost an infinite amount of time.

[Example of loading category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uit36.png)

I'm pretty sure that the codes of the categories that work  and the categories that don't are the same (for reference, I copied and pasted and adjusted each different category accordingly, which could also be an issue but I'm not sure), and are getting their data from the appropriate sites.

Is it perhaps there are too many parsers (RssParser does the actual parsing and seven different "RssService"s use the parser to parse the data from each different category) for my app to work with? My app does seem to crash once in a while though...

I will post my codes below:

**MainActivity.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /* adds the fragment to the activity */

    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;
    private String[] titles;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Code to run when an item in the navigation drawer gets clicked
            selectItem(position);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        drawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //Initialize the ListView
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, titles));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        //Display the correct fragment.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
            setActionBarTitle(currentPosition);
        } else {
            selectItem(0);

        }
        //Create the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

            //Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            //Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                        Fragment fragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag("visible_fragment");

                        if (fragment instanceof TopFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 0;
                        }
                        if (fragment instanceof LifestyleFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 1;
                        }
                        if (fragment instanceof EntFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 2;
                        }
                        if (fragment instanceof NewsFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 3;
                        }
                        if (fragment instanceof FeaturesFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 4;
                        }
                        if (fragment instanceof AcademicsFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 5;
                        }
                        if (fragment instanceof FashionFragment) {
                            currentPosition = 6;
                        }
                        setActionBarTitle(currentPosition);
                        drawerList.setItemChecked(currentPosition, true);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        currentPosition = position;
        Fragment fragment;
        switch(position) {
            case 1:
                fragment = new LifestyleFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new EntFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new NewsFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new FeaturesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new AcademicsFragment();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new FashionFragment();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new TopFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "visible_fragment");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
        //Set the action bar title
        setActionBarTitle(position);
        //Close the drawer
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("position", currentPosition);
    }

    private void setActionBarTitle(int position) {
        String title="";
        titles=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        if (position == 0){
            title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        } else {
            title = titles[position];
        }
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
        setIntent("This is example text");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void setIntent(String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**RssItem.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

public class RssItem {

    private final String title;
    private final String link;
    private final String pubDate;

    public RssItem(String title, String link, String pubDate) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }
}
```

**RssParser.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.util.Xml;


public class RssParser {
    // We don't use namespaces
    private final String ns = null;

    public List<RssItem> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(inputStream, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFeed(parser);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private List<RssItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
        String title = null;
        String link = null;
        String pubDate = null;

        List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("link")) {
                link = readLink(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("pubDate")) {
                pubDate = readDate(parser);
            }

            if (title != null && link != null && pubDate != null) {
                RssItem item = new RssItem(title, link, pubDate);
                items.add(item);
                title = null;
                link = null;
                pubDate = null;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
        String link = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
        return link;
    }

    private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return title;
    }

    private String readDate(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "pubDate");
        String pubDate = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "pubDate");
        return pubDate;
    }

    // For the tags title and link, extract their text values.
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Constants.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;


public class Constants {

    public static final String TAG = "Teen10MagazineApp";

}
```

**RssAdapter.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    /* puts the RSS items in a list */

    private final List<RssItem> items;
    private final Context context;

    public RssAdapter(Context context, List<RssItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTitle;
    }
}
```

Along with the main codes, for the sake of time, I will post the codes of one category that works (the fragment it is placed in and the RssService used to get it) and the codes of one that doesn't work. If you need more information or codes, please contact me and I will be happy to provide information:

**LifeStyleFragment.java** (*Works*):

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class LifestyleFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            startService();
        } else {
            // If we are returning from a configuration change:
            // "view" is still attached to the previous view hierarchy
            // so we need to remove it and re-attach it to the current one
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void startService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RssService_Lifestyle.class);
        intent.putExtra(RssService_Lifestyle.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }

    private final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            List<RssItem> items = (List<RssItem>) resultData.getSerializable(RssService_Lifestyle.ITEMS);
            if (items != null) {
                RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getActivity(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred while downloading the rss feed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        };
    };

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**RssService_Lifestyle.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class RssService_Lifestyle extends IntentService {
    /* parse the rss feed on lifestyle and send the list of items to LifestyleFragment */


    private static final String RSS_LINK = "http://www.teen10mag.com/category/lifestyle/feed/";
    public static final String ITEMS = "items";
    public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";

    public RssService_Lifestyle() {
        super("RssService_Lifestyle");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
        List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
        try {
            RssParser parser = new RssParser();
            rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
        } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
            Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
        receiver.send(0, bundle);
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(String link) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Exception while retrieving the input stream", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**AcademicsFragment.java** (*Doesn't work*):

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AcademicsFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            startService();
        } else {
            // If we are returning from a configuration change:
            // "view" is still attached to the previous view hierarchy
            // so we need to remove it and re-attach it to the current one
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void startService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RssService_Academics.class);
        intent.putExtra(RssService_Academics.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }

    private final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            List<RssItem> items = (List<RssItem>) resultData.getSerializable(RssService_Academics.ITEMS);
            if (items != null) {
                RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getActivity(), items);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred while downloading the rss feed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**RssService_Academics.java**:

```js
package com.hfad.teen10magazine;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class RssService_Academics extends IntentService {
    /* parse the rss feed on academics and send the list of items to AcademicsFragment */


    private static final String RSS_LINK = "http://www.teen10mag.com/category/academics/feed/";
    public static final String ITEMS = "items";
    public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";

    public RssService_Academics() {
        super("RssService_Academics");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
        List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
        try {
            RssParser parser = new RssParser();
            rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
        } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
            Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
        receiver.send(0, bundle);
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(String link) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Exception while retrieving the input stream", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first question, so I tried to be as detailed as possible. If my explanations were unreasonably lengthy, I do apologize. This is also my first time coding something this extensive, so forgive me if I seem to make amateur mistakes...

Thank you in advance for all of your help!!

**[EDIT]**
When I click on the category that doesn't work, the logcat turns up like this:

```js
09-21 19:29:59.237 1541-1866/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.hfad.teen10magazine/.RssService_News (has extras) } U=0: not found
09-21 19:30:13.209 2808-2808/com.hfad.teen10magazine I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-21 19:30:21.122 2808-2814/com.hfad.teen10magazine W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.025ms`
```

Comment: If it crash, you may have some detailled logs that will help us find what's wrong.

Comment: @Nawako It hasn't crashed yet, but I did put up the logcat for when the category doesn't work in the "[EDIT]"